# Use jq to read a file and build a json with data from file

Tags: json, jq

I have a simple file like:

```
keya="valuea valueb"
keyb=""
keyc="valuex"
```

I would like to convert this file into JSON with following structure:

```
{
    "keya": ["valuea", "valueb"],
    "keyb": [],
    "keyc": ["valuex"]
}
```

Is there anyway to perform it using only jq? I was doing this parse on python but I would be glad If was possible to solve all using only jq.

Comment: I doubt it since `jq` is used to parse JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the value part is JSON:

```bash
jq -Rn '
  reduce (inputs / "=") as [$key, $value] ({};
    .[$key] = ($value | fromjson / " ")
  )
' input.txt
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2Sdhvz7WzeY)

Otherwise, just removing the first and last `"` from it:

```bash
jq -Rn '
  reduce (inputs / "=") as [$key, $value] ({};
    .[$key] = ($value | ltrimstr("\"") | rtrimstr("\"") / " ")
  )
' input.txt
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bcEdwQSWWVi)

The most robust approach, however, would be a regex matching, e.g. using `capture`:

```bash
jq -Rn '
  [inputs | capture("^(?<key>[^=]+)=\"(?<value>.*)\"$") | .value /= " "]
  | from_entries
' input.txt
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5a5GIgjehnF)

Output:

```json
{
  "keya": [
    "valuea",
    "valueb"
  ],
  "keyb": [],
  "keyc": [
    "valuex"
  ]
}
```

Comment: is possible to use a file as input?

Comment: @placplacboom Sure, you could provide it as argument like I did (`jq '…' input.txt`), or by redirecting it (`jq '…' < input.txt`).

Comment: You are a god like!

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work on my computer..its creating an empty json and same content works on jqplay..any idea?

Comment: Just first option works..all good, it solves my problem! Tyvm

Comment: @placplacboom - Note that the first and second options are not robust, in the sense that they assume that there is no "=" in any of the values.